# Redirect in Mojolicious

Tags: mojolicious

I am working on a project in Mojolicious and I do not know how to redirect through a button to another page. For example I have pagina1.pl and I want that by means of a button send me to pagina2.pl. How do I do it?

Comment: Hello, I would like ot help but the question is not quite clear. Mojolicious pages are not in different pl files they are in 1 for mojo::lite apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `button_to` tag helper to do redirects to other routes. You can find more information in the [documentation](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/TagHelpers#button_to)